# Update OrderedDict's value at position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

How would I update OrderedDict's values at certain position (beginning from 0)?
So:

```
od = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
od.update({'b': 4}) # a=1, b=4, c=3
od.update_values(2, 1)  # a=2, b=1, c=3
```

Comment: Note that initializing your OrderedDict that way **will not** guarantee that they're inserted in the a,b,c order.

Comment: Yeah: *The OrderedDict constructor and update() method both accept keyword arguments, but their order is lost because Python’s function call semantics pass-in keyword arguments using a regular unordered dictionary.* [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: To avoid that, you could pass in a list of tuples instead. Like `OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])`, or `OrderedDict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple - just use `od[od.keys()[x]] = y`

This works for dictionaries too (although that would be pointless.) The code simply takes a `list` of the keys of the orderedDict, then takes the entry at the desired position from the list, and then uses that string as a key for the original orderedDict.

Comment: Thank you! Easier than I thought :D

Comment: Well, python often is like that, especially with things like lambdas and list comprehension.

If this resolved your question, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: For python 3 where .keys() are generators use `od[list(od.keys())[x]] = y`

Answer (score 1):

You can update an ordered dict in place for an existing element and not change the order:

```
>>> od=MyOD(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))
>>> for i, k in enumerate(od):
...    if i==1:
...        od[k]=1
... 
>>> od
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 3)])
```

If you want a method to do that, just subclass OrderedDict:

```
class MyOD(OrderedDict):
    def update_pos(self, pos, val):
        for i, k in enumerate(self):
            if i==pos:
                self[k]=val
                return

>>> od=MyOD(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))
>>> od
MyOD([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> od.update_pos(1, 22)
>>> od
MyOD([('a', 1), ('b', 22), ('c', 3)])
```